# Kafka message to websocket

Tags: websocket, akka-stream, akka-http

I am trying to write a Kafka consumer to websocket flow using reactive-kafka, akka-http and akka-stream.

```
  val publisherActor = actorSystem.actorOf(CommandPublisher.props)
  val publisher = ActorPublisher[String](publisherActor)
  val commandSource = Source.fromPublisher(publisher) map toMessage
  def toMessage(c: String): Message = TextMessage.Strict(c)

  class CommandPublisher extends ActorPublisher[String] {
    override def receive = {
      case cmd: String =>
        if (isActive && totalDemand > 0)
          onNext(cmd)
    }
  }

  object CommandPublisher {
    def props: Props = Props(new CommandPublisher())
  }

  // This is the route 
  def mainFlow(): Route = {
    path("ws" / "commands" ) {
       handleWebSocketMessages(Flow.fromSinkAndSource(Sink.ignore, commandSource))
    } 
  }
```

From the kafka consumer (omitted here), I do a `publisherActor ! commandString` to dynamically add content to the websocket.

However, I run into this exception in the backend when I start multiple clients to the websocket:

```
[ERROR] [03/31/2016 21:17:10.335] [KafkaWs-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3][akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(KafkaWs)] WebSocket handler failed with can not subscribe the same subscriber multiple times (see reactive-streams specification, rules 1.10 and 2.12)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: can not subscribe the same subscriber multiple times (see reactive-streams specification, rules 1.10 and 2.12)
  at akka.stream.impl.ReactiveStreamsCompliance$.canNotSubscribeTheSameSubscriberMultipleTimesException(ReactiveStreamsCompliance.scala:35)
  at akka.stream.actor.ActorPublisher$class.aroundReceive(ActorPublisher.scala:295)
  ...
```

Can't one flow be used for all websocket clients? Or should the flow/publisher actor be created per client?

Here, I intend to send out "current"/ "live" notifications to all websocket clients. History of notifications is irrelevant and needs to be ignored for new clients.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to bear bad news, but it looks like this is the explicit design of `akka` with respect to . You cannot reuse the *instance* of the flow for all clients as you want to. The fanout must be "explicit" as a consequence of the Rx model.

Examples I have come across use a routee-specific `Flow`:

```
  // The flow from beginning to end to be passed into handleWebsocketMessages
  def websocketDispatchFlow(sender: String): Flow[Message, Message, Unit] =
    Flow[Message]
      // First we convert the TextMessage to a ReceivedMessage
      .collect { case TextMessage.Strict(msg) => ReceivedMessage(sender, msg) }
      // Then we send the message to the dispatch actor which fans it out
      .via(dispatchActorFlow(sender))
      // The message is converted back to a TextMessage for serialization across the socket
      .map { case ReceivedMessage(from, msg) => TextMessage.Strict(s"$from: $msg") }

  def route =
    (get & path("chat") & parameter('name)) { name =>
      handleWebsocketMessages(websocketDispatchFlow(sender = name))
    }
```

Here is a discussion on it:

> And this is exactly what I don't like in Akka Stream, this explicit
>   fan-out. When I receive a data source from somewhere that I want to
>   process (e.g. Observable or a Source), I just want to subscribe to it
>   and I don't want to care on whether it's cold or hot or whether it's
>   been subscribed by other subscribers or not. This is my river analogy.
>   The river should not care about who drinks from it and the drinkers
>   should not care about the river's source or about how many other
>   drinkers there are. My sample, that is equivalent to the one Mathias
>   provided, does share the data-source, but it simply does reference
>   counting and you can have 2 subscribers or you can have 100, doesn't
>   matter. And here I've gotten fancy, but reference counting doesn't
>   work if you don't want to lose events or if you want to ensure that
>   the stream remains always-on. But then you use `ConnectableObservable`
>   which has `connect(): Cancelable` and that's a perfect fit for say ...
>   a Play's LifeCycle Plugin. And underlying that you can use a
>   BehaviorSubject or a ReplaySubject if you want to repeat previous
>   values for new subscribers. And things just work after that, no manual
>   drawing of that connections graph needed.
>   ...
>   ... (this is from https://bionicspirit.com/blog/2015/09/06/monifu-vs-akka-streams.html)
>   ...
>   For functions that take an Observable and return an Observable, we
>   indeed have lift, which is the closest thing to something that has a
>   name and can be used to great effect in Monifu for `Subject` or other
>   Observable types because of the LiftOperators1 (and 2), which is what
>   makes it possible to transform Observables without losing their type -
>   this is an OOP-ish improvement over what RxJava does with `lift`.
>
> But, such functions are not equivalent to `Processor` / `Subject`. The
>   difference is that `Subject` is at the same time a consumer and a
>   producer. This means that subscribers do not get to control exactly
>   when the data-source starts and that the data-source is in essence
>   *hot* (meaning that multiple subscribers share the same data-source). In Rx it's totally fine if you model *cold* observables (meaning
>   observables that start a new data-source per each individual
>   subscriber). On the other hand in Rx (in general) it's not OK to have
>   data sources that can be subscribed only once and then that's it. The
>   only exception to this rule in Monifu are the Observables produced by
>   the GroupBy operator, but that's like the exception that confirms the
>   rule.
>
> What this means, especially coupled with another restriction of the
>   contract of both Monifu and the Reactive Streams protocol (thou shall
>   not subscribe multiple times with the same consumer), is that a
>   `Subject` or a `Processor` instance is not reusable. In order for such
>   an instance to be reusable, the Rx model would need a factory of
>   `Processor`. Furthermore this means that whenever you want to use a
>   `Subject` / `Processor`, your data source must automatically be *hot*
>   (shareable between multiple subscribers).

Comment: Interestingly, I adopted my code from https://github.com/J-Technologies/akka-http-websocket-activator-template which surprisingly works. It uses Source.actorPublisher instead of Source.fromPublisher - that is the only difference. Not able to understand why that works, and mine doesnt

Comment: I'm pretty sure the post I cited is accurate... so it means, you must be using it like a regular Actor and not hooked to a ReactiveStreams compliant

Comment: From `ActorPublisher` it says:  /**
   * Create a [[org.reactivestreams.Publisher]] backed by a [[ActorPublisher]] actor. It can be
   * attached to a [[org.reactivestreams.Subscriber]] or be used as an input source for a
   * [[akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow]].
   */